# Collection view cell with horizontal inset does not remain centred when scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Hey I have a collection view with the following scrolling behaviour:

[image]

The cells need to have a spacing of 16 pts between them and remain centered when scrolled. You can see in the demo only the first and last cell remain centred. My collection view width is the same width as the screen. Setup in `viewDidLoad` like so:

```
func setupCollectionView() {
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "SubtopicCollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SubtopicCollectionCell")
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 16
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(flowLayout, animated: false)
    }
```

The various delegate methods as follows:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: SubtopicCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SubtopicCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! SubtopicCollectionCell
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width * 0.78, height: collectionView.frame.size.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 40, bottom: 0, right: 40)
    }
```

It's important that part of the next cell is displayed on the screen with the current cell centred (like the first and last cell in the demo). How do I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: If you pass UIEdgeInsets.zero  then it scrolling is working ?

Comment: My suggestion is you should create cell with full width and adjust 40 value from cell it self

Comment: @JonSnow I did that, but using this method only one card will be on the screen at a time. I need to show one card and the edge of the next card.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve with following simple calculation in your collectionViewLayout function.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    let cellWidth = CellWidth * CellCount
    let spacingWidth = CellSpacing * (CellCount - 1)

    let leftInset = (collectionViewWidth - CGFloat(CellWidth + SpacingWidth)) / 2
    let rightInset = leftInset

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftInset, 0, rightInset)
}
```

don't forget to implement following protocol

```
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

Comment: In Swift 3, the new method signature is `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int)`

Comment: what is different about your code to mine? I am already using a left and right inset that are the same size.

Answer (score -1):

flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0